# Javascript (jQuery) Client is not working with python webservice

Tags: javascript, python, web-services

I'm trying to build a small restful web service with python. Therefore I used flask (and now bottle).

For testing purposes I wrote a small android application and everything works just fine. I can use POST, GET and DELETE requests from my phone. I also used the program "curl" to check the service - and it worked, too!

Now I thought about writing a javascript client - easier said, than done.

The problem is, I just can not get any response from my server. The request is definitely delivered to my server and I can also see in my logfiles that it responds with ""GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20".

First I thought there is a problem with flask (maybe the response is in an unreadable format?!) and I tried the framework bottle which is very similar. I wrote a very, very simple service and client. But I am still not able to print the servers response on my client.

**Server.py:**

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

**Client.js**

```
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
var server = "http://localhost:8080";

// HTTP GET
function getRequestToServer() {
"use strict";

$.get(
server,
function(data) {
   alert('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
```

}

Please keep in mind that this is a very simplified example. In my original program I used JSON but I thought reducing it to the "core" problem is easier to understand.

I also used the api from api.openweathermap.org to see if the client has any problems, but in this case I receive at least a `[object Object]`. I also have written the client to print the JSON-data and it worked fine - but not with my web service.

Hope anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: works for me. Is there some error in the browser logs?

Comment: No error in browser log! It shows: Response: Δ37ms
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Date: Fri, 03 Oct 2014 18:17:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: How do you deliver your client.js into the user's browser?

Comment: This might be a Same Origin Policy issue.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi: I tried to import the .js in the header area and also as a direct script in my html-body

Comment: He Guys. One thing I recognized is that my request always has an HTTP/1.1-header whereas my server only responds with HTTP/1.0 . Could this be the root of all evil?